# Cloud storage service at azure?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services

Do Azure have a low-cost cloud storage service like [Amazon Glacier](http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<del>No, Microsoft Azure does not offer a service equivalent to Amazon Glacier. Glacier is built on top of Amazon S3. Equivalent to Amazon S3 is Microsoft Azure Blob Storage.</del>

**UPDATE - 06-November-2017**

Recently Microsoft Azure offered a new access tier called `Archive Tier` which is similar to Amazon Glacier (and other cloud provider's long term storage solution for archival purpose). You can read more about this here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/announcing-the-public-preview-of-azure-archive-blob-storage-and-blob-level-tiering/. I also wrote a blog post about the same that you can read here: https://gauravmantri.com/2017/10/15/understanding-azure-storage-blob-access-tiers/.

Comment: Note that S3 has a reduced redundancy price point; Windows Azure has local redundancy (your data will be redundant across a few machines, but not across data centers) that is a cheaper price point. So you could save a little over standard geo-redundant storage pricing but nothing quite like Glacier today.

Comment: Still incomparable Glacier costs $0.01/GB, while Azure LRS blob costs $0.024 per GB and Azure Backup (the latest new service) costs 0.20 per GB.

Answer (score 0):

As an update to the other answer, Azure does have an semi-equivalent service in their blob storage in that you can set up your storage with a "Cold" access tier. You pay less per GB of storage, but you pay more for access against that data. In contrast to Amazon Glacier, you don't have the delay to access the data that Glacier comes with, but you do pay the same price or more (depending on your Glacier retrieval timing).

On the flip side, you can set up storage with a "Hot" access tier and pay ~80% more per GB stored, but pay half the price for access operations.

You can find the current pricing for Azure blob storage at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/ and current pricing for the various Glacier retrieval tiers at https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/pricing/